# Reduced representation of my solutions space by mapping permutations to the same element

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Given two sets $X$ and $Y$:

$x \in X, \textit{x can be represented as a vector }x = (x_1,...,x_n) \textit{where }x_i \textit{ is an integer in the interval } [0,N]  $

What would be a surjective function $f:X  →  Y$ that maps all the elements in $X$ to elements in $Y$, in such a way that vectors $x \in X$ that are permutations of each other have all the same image $y \in Y$? Essentially I am looking for an "encoding" (not sure if that is the right term) that would allow me to represent the elements in $X$ as elements of $Y$, programatically applying the function $f$ on $X$, and then at some point I would also need to apply the right inverse of $f$ on $Y$ (so I can generate one of the many tuples $x$ that maps to a given $y$)

I would like $f$ to be as computationally cheap as possible, since the tuples $x$ are quite long. For example, may be $f$ could be a function $f:(x_1,...,x_n)   →  (y_1, y_2)$, where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the sum and the product of all the entries in the tuple respectively. But I don't know if this $f$ would work, since I lack the maths to prove that elements that are not permutations would always have a different image, and also I don't know how I would efficiently compute the right inverse.

Search terms and references suggestions are also welcome.

EDIT: Ive edited the question to make it clearer as from the comments I can se that it was a bit misleading.

Thank you!

Comment: Suitable encodings for $X$ are certainly possible, but you haven't said anything at all about $Y$ other than that it is the codomain of $f$, so we have absolutely no information on which to base an encoding of it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, thanks for your comment and aswers. I can see that if I wasn't clear enough, I have updated the question. Your answer below does provide valid *f* (it would be the function that sorts the elements, and $Y$ would be the codomain of that function, i.e. the sorted tuples,). However, I am wondering whether there is a computationally cheaper $f$ (even if the right inverse is expensive). Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the cost of sorting here.  Such an $f$ would mean that the mapping $x \mapsto f^{-1}(f(x))$ would carry any $x$ to a "preferred" permutation. This preferred permulation is effectively a "sorted" version of $x$ (though perhaps not in the traditional order). If there were some slick way of accomplishing this, it could be adapted to be an improved sorting algorithm. So you are still sorting. But this is a heuristic argument, so it could be wrong.